# trie implementation throws shrinker error in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, trie

I'm working on a search that I can use with [flutter_typeahed](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_typeahead) package.
I found a package called `trie`, but it doesn't have null safety so I thought of including that and contribute to the project as well as my own.

Since the entire `trie` file is quite big, I'm providing a link to [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/aTH2Baz1).

This is the `Search` class that I've written:

```
class Search {
  final Map<String, RecipeModel> _map = Map.fromIterable(
      Store.instance.getAllRecipes(),
      key: (recipe) => RecipeModel().recipeName!);

  late final Trie trie;
  Search() {
    // This will be O[n]
    trie = Trie.list(_map.keys.toList());
  }

  late RecipeModel recipe;

  RecipeModel returnRecipe(String? suggestion) {
    if (suggestion == null) return recipe;
    // This will be O(1) instead of O(n) [better]
    final RecipeModel? found = _map[suggestion];
    return found ?? recipe;
  }

  List<String> returnSuggestions(String prefix) {
    //will return O[W*L] ad-hoc search was O[n^2]
    return trie.getAllWordsWithPrefix(prefix);
  }
}
```

But I'm getting the following error:

```
Cannot fit requested classes in a single dex file (# methods: 66909 > 65536)
com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives: 
The number of method references in a .dex file cannot exceed 64K.

The shrinker may have failed to optimize the Java bytecode.
To disable the shrinker, pass the `--no-shrink` flag to this command.
```

What can I do to make my code efficient and fix the error?

N.B: RecipeModel is simply a model which holds recipeName, authorId etc. And `Store.instance.getAllRecipes(),` returns a list of recipes

Comment: I doubt the dex error is related to your use of `trie` as it's pure Dart. As an aside, do you actually notice the difference between O(W*L) and O(N^2)? I'd have thought the dictionary would have to be enormous to notice the difference in practical use cases, given how memory inefficient tries are.

Comment: then what might be the reason for the error? And yes, I do think that implementing a trie with O(W*L) is pretty close to O(N^2). But I was tasked with implementing a better search algorithm than just one that does O(N^2) and trie is the only thing that came to mind

Comment: Just search for the dex error. I'm pretty sure there are lots of solutions out there.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I had to enable [multidex](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex). And I had to change the following things:

```
defaultConfig {
    // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
    applicationId "com.example.food_app"
    minSdkVersion 17
    targetSdkVersion 30
    versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
    versionName flutterVersionName
    multiDexEnabled true // add this line
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1' // add this one
}
```